# Removing acronyms using regex , based on uppercase characters following parenthesis

Tags: python, regex, string, uppercase, python-re

How to remove the following:

- Acronyms starting with opening bracket and followed by upper case or
  number: e.g. '(ABC' or '(ABC)' or '(ABC-2A)' or '(ABC-1)'.

But **NOT** the words that are between parenthesis starting with uppercase and followed by lowercase e.g. '(Bobby)' or '(Bob went to the beach..)' --> This is the part I am struggling with.

```
text = ['(ABC went to the beach', 'The girl (ABC-2A) is walking', 'The dog (Bobby) is being walked', 'They are there (ABC)' ]
for string in text:
  cleaned_acronyms = re.sub(r'\([A-Z]*\)?', '', string)
  print(cleaned_acronyms)

#current output:
>> 'went to the beach' #Correct
>>'The girl -2A) is walking' #Not correct
>>'The dog obby) is being walked' #Not correct
>>'They are there' #Correct


#desired & correct output:
>> 'went to the beach'
>>'The girl is walking'
>>'The dog (Bobby) is being walked' #(Bobby) is NOT an acronym (uppercase+lowercase)
>>'They are there'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a try with a negative lookahead:

```
\((?![A-Z][a-z])[A-Z\d-]+\)?\s*
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/guohRO/1)

- `\(` - A literal opening paranthesis.
- `(?![A-Z][a-z])` - Negative lookahead to assert position not followed by uppercase followed by lowercase.
- `[A-Z\d-]+` - Match 1+ uppercase alpha chars, digits or hyphens.
- `\)?` - An optional literal closing paranthesis.
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespace characters.

Some sample Python script:

```
import re
text = ['(ABC went to the beach', 'The girl (ABC-2A) is walking', 'The dog (Bobby) is being walked', 'They are there (ABC)' ]
for string in text:
  cleaned_acronyms = re.sub(r'\((?![A-Z][a-z])[A-Z\d-]+\)?\s*', '', string)
  print(cleaned_acronyms)
```

Prints:

```
went to the beach
The girl is walking
The dog (Bobby) is being walked
They are there
```

Comment: All answers were very helpful. I accepted yours as you provided an explanation for each part, which really helps me understand.

Answer (score 2):

Using `\([A-Z\-0-9]{2,}\)?` in the following context:

```
import re

text = ['(ABC went to the beach', 'The girl (ABC-2A) is walking', 'The dog (Bobby) is being walked', 'They are there (ABC)' ]
for string in text:
  cleaned_acronyms = re.sub(r'\([A-Z\-0-9]{2,}\)?', '', string)
  print(cleaned_acronyms)
```

I get these results:

```
' went to the beach'
'The girl  is walking'
'The dog (Bobby) is being walked'
'They are there '
```

Comment: You may want to catch the spaces too for a slight better result like in the OP. =) ++

Comment: I realise, but after seeing your answer was so much better than my own I decided it would be selfish to try and take the "best answer" from you. Good job!

Comment: Don't worry about anything like that. Improve your answer for the better and let OP decide what answers work best for him. Don't do yoursefl down!

Comment: Both your answers are great. Thanks a lot for your effort!

Answer (score 1):

Using pattern `\([A-Z0-9\-]+\)`

**Ex:**

```
import re

text = ['ABC went to the beach', 'The girl (ABC-2A) is walking', 'The dog (Bobby) is being walked', 'They are there (ABC)' ]
ptrn = re.compile(r"\([A-Z0-9\-]+\)")
for i in text:
    print(ptrn.sub("", i))
```

**Output:**

```
ABC went to the beach
The girl  is walking
The dog (Bobby) is being walked
They are there
```

Comment: Looks like you got the wrong sample data here. The first element starts with `(ABC` without a closing paranthesis.

Comment: oh...i thought that was a typo